# Transparent NSWindow with layer backed NSView

Tags: macos, nswindow, appkit, caemitterlayer

I adapted Apple's [RoundTransparentWindow](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/RoundTransparentWindow/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html) sample project to create a `NSWindow` and `NSView` which I use to have a transparent window (obviously the children of the `NSView` are visible, just not the window or the view's background).

I would like to add a `CAEmitterLayer` for particle effects to this window, but as soon as I set the view to layer backed (which [seems to be](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/SettingUpLayerObjects/SettingUpLayerObjects.html) a requirement of `CAEmitterLayer`) with

```
    self.view.wantsLayer    = true
```

the view loses its transparency and becomes opaque.

How can I have a transparent, layer-backed `NSWindow`? Or, is it possible to use `CAEmitterLayer` in some other way on a transparent window?

Comment: `CAEmitterLayer` will work with a transparent window if you create a custom view for it.

Comment: That's encouraging! I'm using a custom view at the moment based on the one used in `RoundTransparentWindow`: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/RoundTransparentWindow/Listings/Classes_CustomView_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000401-Classes_CustomView_m-DontLinkElementID_6 , but I must be doing something wrong. Can you unpack what the custom view needs?

Comment: I uploaded a [quick project](https://github.com/dylib/Fire) for you to play with ... (it's definitely not perfect, although it should give you some idea on how a CAEmitterLayer can be used within a transparent window).  :)

Comment: Thanks so much! Looking forward to checking it out. Just glad that it's possible. Thought it might be too "edge case"

Comment: You're welcome! ... I'm total edge case, so you're talking to the right guy. I also cleaned up the project a bit just now (removed redundant AppDelegate, etc.). If you have more questions just let me know.

Comment: That worked, thanks so much! Specifically this is what I was missing for a layer-backed view (converted to swift). In fact I could drop a lot of the sample Apple code, including the drawRect call that was in RoundTransparentView.
 let thisWindow = animationWindowController?.window
        thisWindow?.opaque = false
        thisWindow?.backgroundColor = NSColor(deviceWhite: 0.0, alpha: 0.0). 
        animationWindowController?.showWindow(self) 

Do you want to pop that in an answer so I can mark it as correct? Thanks again!